# cannot get data from IR sensor on embedded linux using official driver

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, infrared, nanopi

I run a linux image (made with buildroot and the 4.11.2 kernel provided by the manufacturer) on a nanopi NEO air board with an IR sensor plugged directly on the IR pin. I want to use the sensor to get data from an IR remote control.

I followed the procedure found [here](http://linux-sunxi.org/IR#mainline_kernel_.284.x.29_and_sunxi-cir), with the same driver, and got the same results, but I cannot get any data from `/dev/input/eventX`, nor can I get my remote to appear in `/proc/bus/input/devices` (I tried sending data with the remote control when inserting the driver, or at boot when the driver is builtin, but it obviously didn't work and I didn't find much information on that).

I also tried with lirc and evtest / irrecord, but I still can't get any data and I believe the problem is elsewhere.

I tested the sensor and the remote with an oscilloscope, so I know that the sensor is getting frames from the remote. I'm also fairly sure it's not a protocol mismatch on the driver's side.

So I have two questions :

- Where is the problem here and why can't I get anything when I run `cat /dev/input/eventX` ?
- Is my remote supposed to show in `/proc/bus/input/devices` and is there a pairing procedure that I should be aware of ?

Please excuse me if those are trivial questions (I never worked on IR before) and thank you in advance.

## **EDIT**

I've managed to get my remote to work with one of the old images provided by the manufacturer (kernel 3.4.39-h3) and I've noticed that :

- The driver I'm using doesn't work (it never goes into the interrupt function that reads the FIFO and the physical addresses associated to the FIFO are always at 0)
- The driver for the old image registers the following input device in its init function (hardcoded), which I then use to get data from the remote (using `cat /dev/input/event1`) :

```
    pi@NanoPi-NEO-Air:~$ cat /proc/bus/input/devices
    ...    
    I: Bus=0019 Vendor=0001 Product=0001 Version=0100
    N: Name="sunxi-ir"
    P: Phys=RemoteIR/input1
    S: Sysfs=/devices/virtual/input/input1
    U: Uniq=
    H: Handlers=sysrq kbd event1 cpufreq_interactive 
    B: PROP=0
    B: EV=100003
    B: KEY=ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff fffffffe
```

So now I'm wondering if I should also register that device in the driver I'm using and if so, how should I do it ?

Comment: Are you actually using `eventX` or the actual number associated to your device like `event0`? There's documentation on that page you link to that shows how to get the number for your particular device (if you don't have it already).

Comment: I tried both `event0` and `event1`, just to be sure, but now I think the problem actually comes from the driver. I just edited my post to reflect that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of my workmate solved it, the problem was in the dts.
In `sun8i-h3-nanopi-neo-air.dts`, just activating the IR like this :

```
&ir {
    status = "okay";
};
```

isn't enough, the pins for the IR must be redefined too :

```
​&ir {
​    pinctrl-names = "default";
​    pinctrl-0 = <&ir_pins_a>;
​    status = "okay";
​};
```

Hope this will help somebody.

Comment: How I can find `sun8i-h3-nanopi-neo-air.dts` file?, I need recompile kernel or module ?

Comment: Hi, you can find it in a (recent) vanilla linux kernel source (https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/arch/arm/boot/dts/sun8i-h3-nanopi-neo-air.dts)